# selenium wait until all my list element is clickable

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

here is my code:
this all_plus_icons returns a list of 10 elements of the page which I need to wait until all these elements are clickable in selenium and click each of them.

```
all_plus_icons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='block-views-tenders-block']/div/div/div[2]/div//div[1]/h5/span/i")

for i in all_plus_icons:
    time.sleep(10)
    i.click()
```

the above code sometimes generates an error as :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <i class="ic ac-icon-add"></i> is not clickable at point (831, 605). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cc_banner cc_container cc_container--open">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)
```

I used this :

```
WebDriverWait(driver , 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH , "//*[@id='block-views-tenders-block']/div/div/div[2]/div//div[1]/h5/span/i")))
```

but it does not work. how can I make sure all the elements are clickable.
this is the website.[enter link description here](https://www.enabel.be/content/enabel-tenders)

Comment: Are you closing and handling the cookie warning - if you read the error it tells you the element `cc_banner cc_container cc_container--open` would receive the click. Open chrome incognito, open devtools, enter that identifier and it will show you it is the cookie message.

Comment: @TalibDaryabi Which element is `<div class="cc_banner cc_container cc_container--open">`? Update the question with the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that you need to accept Cookies to perform your actions. Try to do this first before clicking elements:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Got it!').click()
WebDriverWait(driver , 20).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , "cc_banner")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try run this code

```
for i in all_plus_icons:
    time.sleep(10)
    i.click()
    driver.refresh
```